# Reverse for 'delete_task/{{todo.id}}' not found. 'delete_task/{{todo.id}}' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: html, django, django-forms, django-urls, django-url-reverse

I am new in django and I have following issue after running:
Reverse for 'delete_task/{{todo.id}}' not found. 'delete_task/{{todo.id}}' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

In my template file index.html I have:

```
<form action="{% url 'delete_task/todo.id'%}" method="post" class = 'delete-link'>
    {% csrf_token%}
    <button type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```

My urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('delete_task/<int:todo_id>', views.delete_task, name='delete_task'),
```

]

My views.py:

```
def delete_task(request, task_id):
    return HttpResponse(task_id)
#the delete_task block is just for test
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *name* of the path is `delete_task`, so the first parameter of the [**`{% url … %}`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url) is `'delete_task`, then the second is the parameter (here `todo.pk`):

```
<form action="{% url 'delete_task' todo.id %}" method="post" class = 'delete-link'>
    {% csrf_token%}
    <button type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you! I am so grateful!

Answer (score 2):

Write like this:

```
<form action="{% url 'delete_task' todo.id %}" method="post" class = 'delete-link'>
{% csrf_token%}
<button type="submit">Delete</button>
```

Problem Solve